# ionic back button not showing last view

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic-view

I am trying to apply back button concept on my ionic app.

Here what i am doing:
i have created my app as in `index.html` file loading all the necessary dependencies.

```
  <ion-nav-bar class="bar-light nav-title-slide-ios7">
      <ion-nav-back-button class="button-clear button-icon">
        <i class="ion-arrow-left-c"></i>
      </ion-nav-back-button>
    </ion-nav-bar>

    <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
```

and i had created a view named `dashboard.html`

```
<ion-view class="bar-light" view-title="Dashboard">
<ion-content scroll="false" class="padding grid-collection has-header">
    <div class="grid-full">
        <div class="grid-child">Play Ground</div>
    </div>
</ion-content>      

<div class="bar bar-footer">
    <a ui-sref="dashboard.create"><button class="button button-positive footer-button">Left</button></a>
    <button class="button button-positive footer-button pull-right">Right</button>
</div>
</ion-view>
<ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
```

Here i have applied a button named Left, on its click a new view should suppose to get open with a back button on its top-left,which is working fine till here.`create-new.html`

```
<ion-view view-title="child">
  <ion-content class="padding">
        <h1>Hellow</h1>
            <h2>World</h2>
               <h3>I am here !</h3>
    </p>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

when i am clicking back button my state is changing but template `create-new.html` remains open ,its not hiding and opening the last `dashboard.html`

Here how i have configured the states.

```
$stateProvider

  // setup an abstract state for the tabs directive
    .state('home', {
      url: '/home',
      templateUrl: 'templates/home.html',
     controller:'authenticateCtrl'
     })
    .state('home.nativelogin', {
      url: '/nativelogin',
      templateUrl: 'templates/login.html',
      controller:'authenticateCtrl'

    })
    .state('dashboard', {
      url: '/dashboard',
      templateUrl:'templates/dashboard.html',
      controller:'dashboardCtrl',
    })
    .state('dashboard.create',{
      url:'/create',
      templateUrl:'templates/create-new.html',
      controller:'dashboardCtrl'
    });

  // if none of the above states are matched, use this as the fallback
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('home');
```

**Edit:*
I just checked there are two div with class `'active'` and `'cached'` they suppose to exchange their class to make the back button work fine but its swapping once to open the `create-new` template but nothing on pressing back button

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention to right **syntax**: remove from `dashboard.html` the tag `<ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>` and use preferably `<ion-footer-bar>` instead of `<div class="bar bar-footer">`:

```
<ion-view class="bar-light" view-title="Dashboard">
<ion-content scroll="false" class="padding grid-collection has-header">
    <div class="grid-full">
        <div class="grid-child">Play Ground</div>
    </div>
</ion-content>
<ion-footer-bar align-title="left" class="bar-assertive">
  <div class="buttons">
    <a ui-sref="dashboard.create" class="button button-positive footer-button">Left</a>
  </div>
  <div class="buttons" ng-click="doSomething()">
    <button class="button">Right</button>
  </div>
</ion-footer-bar> 
</ion-view>
```